# wp_dropdown_categories doesn't display selected value

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I can not see any selected category from my category drop-down list. Here is my code and script.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('hide_empty=0&show_option_none=Select News category&show_count=0&hierarchical=1&depth=0&exclude=1'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");  
function onCatChange() {
    if (dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo home_url('/');?>?&cid="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value+"/#new";
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

When I select any category from the list, it's not display selected category name, it display only the "`Select News category`". please any one can help to see my selected category.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing code as shown below,

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('hide_empty=0&show_option_none=Select News category&show_count=0&hierarchical=1&depth=0&exclude=1'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");  
function onCatChange() {
    if (dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo home_url('/');?>?&cid="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value+"/#new";
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i thought you are not getting my question. My script and all are working fine as i mention above but issue is when i select any category from the drop-down at that time selected category is not display into drop-down. It shows only Select News category i have to display category name which i select instead of this.